# Display multiple instances of an image in HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display an image in a row multiple times, I have coded the following (mix of HTML/PHP/CSS):

```
for ($i=20; $i<=320; $i=$i+300) {
    echo "<style> " 
      . ".test{"
      . "position: absolute;
         left: " . $i . "px;"
      .  "top: " . 430 . "px;"
      . "</style>";
    echo "<img src=http://localhost/Summoner's%20Index/images/scheme.png class=test>" . "<br />" . "<br />";
}
```

My problem is, that each time the image gets placed again, the old disappears, so that in the end there is just one instance of the image. How can I change that?

Comment: This way you are NOT display a image many times. You are displaying the same image in many places. Then In the end you have just the last position visible. Give me a few minutes and I'll post some code.

Comment: Add the current index as prefix to the css class `test` and try it again. Plus wrap a container with `position: relative;` around the images.

Comment: This loop should only loop once because you increment by 300......

Comment: .... and the way your <img> tag is formatted, I doubt any image would appear at all.  You're missing some quotes

Comment: @EatPeanutButter nah, it loops 2times. and there aren't missing any quotes at all, its just a mix of PHP and HTML.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 thanks mate, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

each loop your re-declaring the style, since all images are using the one style, they are all slowly being moved to lay right on top of each other no matter how many times you loop through.

Pull out the style from the loop, instead add some inline css on the img tag, utilizing position absolute and your dynamic top and left values.

```
<?
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++)
{
    $left = $i*300;
    ?><img src='blah.jpg' style='position:absolute; left:<?=$left?>px;'><?  
}
?>
```